# How to use google maps in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, google-maps, maps

I'm creating an application that needs to be able to add/locate/delete tags on map locations, be able to go to a specific address, and retrieve an address from an arbitrary point on the map.

I am thinking the google maps API is what I need to use.  I tried downloading the following code from GitHub:

https://github.com/tranter/qt-google-maps

but I couldn't get it working nor understand what is going on in it.

I tried creating a QWebView widget and using this code:

```
  ui->webView->setUrl(QUrl("http://maps.google.com"));
```

but when I run, nothing shows up in the web view and I get a lot of these types of lines in my application output:

> qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function
>   SSLv23_client_method

I'm pretty much shooting in the dark at this point.  Does anyone have a good easy straightforward way to understand how to use google maps in a qt application?

Answer (score 1):

Use google map plugin for QtLocation : https://github.com/vladest/googlemaps

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added below in .pro file

- `QT += network`
- `-lssl -lcrypto` SSL libraries (libeay32,ssleay32 .dll or .so depending on your platform)